# Export Crystal Reports 2011 to MS Excel 2010

Tags: excel-2010, crystal-reports-2011

We are currently using Crystal Reports 2011 and Excel 2010. Some of our reports have 65k rows and would like to export those file into Excel 2010 file. I found out I am able to export all the data into one sheet if I choose "Microsoft Excel Workbook Data Only" as Excel Export Format but we would like to keep the format and layout as well. Is there any way to export the report which has more than 65k rows into only one sheet of Excel 2010 with formatting? I believe one sheet in Excel 2010 is able to have a million rows.

Thank you.

Comment: I found out that Export to .xlsx is only supported by the Excel Workbook Data Only option and CR 2011 will export data into multiple sheets since the .xls format has the 65k limit. If can't preserve formatting and export to .xlsx - the feature isn't available yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that Export to .xlsx is only supported by the Excel Workbook Data Only option and CR 2011 will export data into multiple sheets since the .xls format has the 65k limit. If can't preserve formatting and export to .xlsx - the feature isn't available yet.